# How to configure to use EntityListeners in Jboss 7?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jboss7.x

I already added `org.eclipse.persistence` module in `JBoss 7`. I cannot use `EntityListeners`. 
If I remove `@EntityListeners(IDInterceptor.class)` from entity, persist operation is ok.
Before an entity is persist, I have to do some operation.

**If I test insert method of DAO with `Junit`, `EntityListeners` is work.**

I use : `JBoss 7`, `Spring 3.5` and `JPA 2.0 (EcliplseLink 2.5.0)`

Let me know, How can I use `EntityListeners` in my web application with `JBoss 7`?

InsuType.java

```
@Entity
@TableGenerator(name = "INSUTYPE_GEN", table = "ID_GEN", pkColumnName = "GEN_NAME", valueColumnName = "GEN_VAL", pkColumnValue = "INSUTYPE_GEN", allocationSize = 10)
@EntityListeners(IDInterceptor.class)
public class InsuType implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "INSUTYPE_GEN")
    private String id;
    private String name;
    //getter and setter
}
```

IDInterceptor.java

```
public class IDInterceptor {
    @PrePersist
    public void onPrePersist(Object obj) {

    }

    //other function
}
```

InsuTypeDAO.java

```
@Repository("InsuTypeDAO")
public class InsuTypeDAO implements IInsuTypeDAO {
    @PersistenceContext
    protected EntityManager em;

    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public InsuType insert(InsuType insuType) throws DAOException {
        em.persist(insuType);
        return insuType;
    }
}
```

If I use `@EntityListeners(IDInterceptor.class)`, I get the following error

```
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerImpl.persist(EntityManagerImpl.java:496) [eclipselink-2.5.0.jar:2.5.0.v20130507-3faac2b]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:240) [spring-orm.jar:3.1.
1.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy57.persist(Unknown Source) at org.ace.insurance.system.common.insutype.persistence.InsuTypeDAO.insert(InsuTypeDAO.java:33) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318) [spring-aop.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) [spring-aop.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) [spring-aop.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110) [spring-tx.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) [spring-aop.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) [spring-aop.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at $Proxy108.insert(Unknown Source) at org.ace.insurance.system.common.insutype.service.InsuTypeService.addNewInsuType(InsuTypeService.java:33) [classes:]
    at org.ace.insurance.web.manage.system.ManageInsuTypeActionBean.addNewInsuType(ManageInsuTypeActionBean.java:52) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:262) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:278) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:39) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50) [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105) [jsf-impl-2.1.7-jbossorg-2.jar:]
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88) [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.5.Final.jar:2.0.
5.Final]
    ... 33 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.enterprise.inject.spi.BeanManager from [Module "org.eclipse.persistence:main" from local module loader @4c5e1
76f (roots: D:\java\JBoss-7.1.1\modules)]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:190)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:468)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:456)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassChecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:423)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:398)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:120)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I get a solution which is `EntityListener` class have to extends `DescriptorEventAdapter`.
Even the `EntityListener` need to inject the spring component, just try as below.
Make sure to use the `static` attribute and `setter property` for spring component/bean.

```
@Component
public class IDInterceptor extends DescriptorEventAdapter {
    private static SomeSpringBean someSpringBean;

    @Autowired(required = true)
    @Qualifier("SomeSpringBean")
    public void setSomeSpringBean(SomeSpringBean bean) {
        someSpringBean = bean;
    }   

    @Override
    public void preInsert(DescriptorEvent event) {

    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like jpa entity listener are not used anymore (@PrePersist), it sound more a config to have working on spring.